# Mudar a action de um formulário conforme condição

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um formulário que faz um update.

Porém eu queria colocar um input do tipo checkbox que ao ser marcado, alterasse a action de meu formulário para delete.

Comment: Alterei a sua pergunta, tinha muita informação não necessária ao meu ver, caso sinta que alterei o sentido da sua pergunta, basta clicar [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/188850/revisions) e clicar em reverter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se obter esse resultado:

```js
function suaFuncao(option) {
  if (option) {
    document.getElementById("seu_form").action = "delete";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("seu_form").action = "update";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="seu_form" action="update">
  Deseja fazer um delete?<input type="checkbox" onclick="suaFuncao(this.checked)">
</form>
```

## Veja funcionando:

[image]

Comment: Funcionou como eu precisava. Achei que seria algo complicado e você fez com poucas linhas. Grata.